# Simplification of an integral involving a linear combination of tensor products of Legendre polynomials

Tags: integration, laplacian, legendre-polynomials

I have this expression:

$$W(x,y)=\sum_{i=0}^{I}\sum_{j=0}^{J}W_{ij}P_i(x)P_j(y)$$

Where $I, J, W_{ij}$ are constants and $P_i , P_j$ are Legendre polynomials.

I want to compute the following equation:

$$F=\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1\frac{W^2}{\sqrt{\frac{\partial^2W/\partial x^2 + \partial^2W/\partial y^2}{W}}}dxdy$$

I want to know if there is any relationship between the Legendre polynomial functions and their derivatives to further simplify this formulation to simply compute the integrals.

Comment: Please do not post links to images, use MathJax to format equations.

Comment: I have Latexified your expressions. Please check them.

Comment: Have you attempted to use the differential equation verified by Legendre polynomials ?

Comment: I have erased the tags "algebra-precalculus" which deals with secondary school algebraic computation...

Comment: What do you mean by  the differential equation verified by Legendre polynomials?

Comment: https://www.iitg.ac.in/shyamashree/Lecture16-2016.pdf

Comment: Is your question connected to finite elements tensor-product bases like [here](https://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/~durufle/montjoie/triangle.php#TriangleHdivFirstFamily) ?

Comment: No, actually it is the generalized subsonic aerodynamic load exerted on a plate, which the Legendre polynomials, 
$$W_{ij}P_i(x)P_j(y)$$ 
 play the role of free vibration mode shapes.